# Can't understand python's code. Try to translate to java

Tags: java, python

I try to translate this python's code to java, but i can't understand strings:

```
crc ^ ord (data[idx]) << 8
```

and

```
return crc & 0xffff
```

Actualy, I can't understand only part with **<< 8** and **& 0xffff**

Full function:

```
def calculateCRC (data):
l = len (data)
crc = 0
idx = 0
l = l - 1
while l >= 0 :
    crc = crc ^ ord (data[idx]) << 8
    idx = idx + 1
    i = 8
    while i != 0:
    if crc & 0x8000:
        crc = crc << 1 ^ 0x1021
    else:
        crc = crc << 1
    i = i - 1
l = l - 1

return crc & 0xffff
```

I know that the SO are nott free code translate service, but i have clear question about python.
So. Can you help me?

Comment: almas shaikh has your translation, but in case you run into performance problems with bit-at-a-time CRC calculation, there's a byte-at-a-type algorithm for just about any flavor of CRC.  The method seems to be due to Aram Perez, in a 1983 IEEE Micro article "Byte-wise CRC Calculations".  PDFs are all over the place.  I found one at http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/fairchild/_appNotes/Byte-wise_CRC_Jun83.pdf

Comment: Apparently, the method goes back a bit farther than that June '83 article.  Apparently, John R. Hill published a table-driven approach in 1979.  I can't find a (free) PDF of that online, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help! Full answer is:

```
public int getCRC(String data)
{
    int l = data.length();
    int crc = 0;
    int idx = 0;
    l = l - 1;
    while (l >= 0)
    {
        crc = crc ^ data.charAt(idx) << 8;
        idx = idx + 1;
        int i = 8;
        while (i != 0)
        {
            if ((crc & 0x8000) != 0)
            {
                crc = crc << 1 ^ 0x1021;
            }
            else
            {
                crc = crc << 1;
            }
            i = i - 1;
        }
        l = l - 1;
    }
return crc & 0xffff;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) for details of ord function. The java equivalent of `crc ^ ord (data[idx]) << 8` would be

```
crc ^ data.charAt(idx) << 8;
```